# Google Cloud Dataflow Error: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have deployed a Google Cloud Dataflow job using Apache Beam which reads from a Kafka source and writes to BigQuery. Data is being written successfully, however I am infrequently receiving an exception with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.processElements(ReduceFnRunner.java:368)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:94)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1324)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:151)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1053)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteGroupedRecordsToFiles$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:180)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.processElements(ReduceFnRunner.java:368)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:94)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1324)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:151)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1053)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:367)
        com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:238)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryRowWriter.close(BigQueryRowWriter.java:76)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteGroupedRecordsToFiles.processElement(WriteGroupedRecordsToFiles.java:73)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:528)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:448)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:301)
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I also receive the following warnings infrequently:

```
Request failed with code 410(or 409), performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 1 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): {URL}
```

When I navigate to the provided URL, I receive either a Method not Allowed message (For Error code 410), or a

```
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

error message (For Error code 409).

Is there a way to debug further as to why this error is occurring?

Comment: There's a chance this might be related to the max number of workers allowed.

If the number of maximum allowed workers is low, the job might not be able to handle the data throughput, maybe the data is still getting inserted because it's automatically retrying this process, as mentioned in the second warning: "performed 1 retries due to unsuccessful status codes."

Try making some tests by increasing this number, you can do that with the "--maxNumWorkers=" flag. If the frequency of these exceptions doesn't lower with a considerably higher number of workers; there's probably another reason.

Comment: Continuing...

Let us know the result of the above suggestion. If that doesn't help, maybe you could share a code snippet of your pipeline.

Also, keep in mind checking if you're using the latest Apache Beam Java SDK and Dataflow SDK versions.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status

Comment: As a side note, the errors you're getting when following those links are most likely because the URLs provided are the HTTP requests that failed (so it's saying to retry thise). When you navigate on there you are essentially sending that request through your internet browser, which will either be an invalid request (message not allowed) or you browser will lack authorization (missing OAuth). 

To your main question, I second expanding throughput. It looks like your elements are retrying properly so the only question is if the requests are actually failing more than normal.

Comment: @Fcojavmelo Thanks for your response. The job never actually scales up to the maximum number of workers set when running, so I don't think that was the issue. The issue currently seems to be resolved by lowering the number of file shards used when writing to BigQuery to decrease the parallelism of the BigQuery import job.

Comment: @Daniel Oliveira Thanks for your response. Do you know how I would be able to view the error URLs with proper authentication directly through the Google Cloud Console by any chance? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this issue will require detailed inspection of your Dataflow job.
My recommendation here is that you file a private issue using this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491268
Here, you can safely share your project number to allow for an inspection and issue troubleshooting.